# What should be the visa type for an under 18 going to a conference in the UK?

Tags: standard-visitor-visas, minors, conferences

I am 17 years old and I have an invitation from a university regarding a conference. Usually, for a conference, a business visa is appropriate but when I clicked that it said `this visa is for adults only`. I then tried to give business (academic) but even that has four options which are:

- research
- teaching
- clinical practice
- formal exchange

I am really confused. What type of visa should I apply for?

Answer (score 2):

I am confused. Where did you click what? I believe you need a standard visitor visa as per the official [Standard Visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa) page:

> You can apply for a Standard Visitor visa if you want to visit the UK for business-related activities, eg: you’re coming to the UK for a conference,

and then there's a [If you're under 18](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/if-youre-under-18) sub-page telling you everything you need to know age wise.

Comment: No, I won't copy-paste the whole sub-page. There are a *lot* of conditions, different for travelling alone and traveling with an adult -- consult the official page, that's why it's there.

Comment: Thanks to you for the answer,I know I have to apply for standard visitor visa and in the form there are three things to fulfill, reason for visit,visa type and visa sub-type.
reason for visit I gave is visit but I'm confused with the visa type as I am under 18 and I can't click on business as a visa type.